# How to divide on Zero in Pandas Dataframe and make 1 column out of 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I did spend few hours on Google but was not able to find solution for my issue.
I'm receiving `dataframe` like this:

```
col1         col2     col3 
2022-03-01   234       0
2022-03-01   342       67
2022-03-01   0         0
2022-03-01   0         23
```

I need to divide `Col2` on `Col3` and result should look like this:

```
col1         col4 
2022-03-01   0      
2022-03-01   5.1
2022-03-01   0        
2022-03-01   0
```

How I can do that ??
With functions like `divide` or `/` I'm always getting error: `decimal./DivizionByZero`

I did try to find any solution but in Google there is always basic stuff, like divide just number on number, not on Zero etc.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no decimals replace infinite values to `0` and then missing values:

```
import numpy as np

df['col4'] = df['col2'].div(df['col3']).replace(np.inf,0).fillna(0)
print (df)
         col1  col2  col3      col4
0  2022-03-01   234     0  0.000000
1  2022-03-01   342    67  5.104478
2  2022-03-01     0     0  0.000000
3  2022-03-01     0    23  0.000000
```

Solution with decimals:

If possible convert to integers:

```
df['col4'] = df['col2'].astype(int).div(df['col3'].astype(int)).replace(np.inf,0).fillna(0)
print (df)
         col1 col2 col3      col4
0  2022-03-01  234    0  0.000000
1  2022-03-01  342   67  5.104478
2  2022-03-01    0    0  0.000000
3  2022-03-01    0   23  0.000000
```

If not, replace `0` to `1` and then set `0` if at least in one column is `0`:

```
df['col4'] = df['col2'].div(df['col3'].replace(0, 1)).mask(df[['col2', 'col3']].eq(0).any(1), 0)
print (df)
         col1 col2 col3                           col4
0  2022-03-01  234    0                              0
1  2022-03-01  342   67  5.104477611940298507462686567
2  2022-03-01    0    0                              0
3  2022-03-01    0   23                              0
```

Comment: np.inf  mean NumPy? I don't have it on my project. Can I use anything else?

Comment: @Sergey - if use `pandas` then it use `numpy`. Add `import numpy as np`

Comment: Second option worked, but how I can remove col2 and col3?

Comment: @Sergey - then use `df = df.drop(['col2','col3'], axis=1)`